# My pixel map image (NSImage) sometimes doesn't look like the RGB values I pass in, Swift Core Graphics Quartz

Tags: swift, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I have two d pixel maps ([Double]) that I encode (correctly) into a [UInt32]), which is fed into a CGDataProvider, which is the source for a CGImage, converted to an NSImage and finally displayed in a custom view with

```
class SingleStepMapView:NSView {
@IBOutlet var dataSource : SingleStepViewController!

override func drawRect(dirtyRect: NSRect) {
    let mapImage = TwoDPixMap(data: dataSource.mapData, 
    width: dataSource.mapWidth, color: dataSource.mapColor).image

    mapImage.drawInRect(self.bounds, fromRect: NSZeroRect, operation: NSCompositingOperation.CompositeSourceAtop, fraction: 1.0)
    return 
}
```

The part where the NSImage is being constructed is in the image property of the TwoDPixMap instance...

```
var image : NSImage {
    var buffer = [UInt32]()
    let bufferScale = 1.0 / (mapMax - mapMin)
    for d in data {
        let scaled = bufferScale * (d - mapMin)
        buffer.append( color.rgba(scaled) )
    }
    let bufferLength = 4 * height * width
    let dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(nil, buffer, bufferLength, nil)!
    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bitsPerPixel = 32
    let bytesPerRow = 4 * width
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    var bitMapInfo = CGBitmapInfo()
    bitMapInfo.insert(.ByteOrderDefault)
    //        let bitMapInfo = CGBitmapInfo(rawValue: CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedFirst.rawValue)
    let interpolate = false
    let renderingIntent = CGColorRenderingIntent.RenderingIntentDefault
    let theImage = CGImageCreate(width, height, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitMapInfo, dataProvider, nil, interpolate, renderingIntent)!
    let value = NSImage(CGImage: theImage, size: NSSize(width: width, height: height))
    return value
}
```

I have checked that the created buffer values are always correct when fed into the `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` call.  In particular for the following examples, which are sixty four `Double` values (from 0.0 to 63.0) which will be mapped into sixty four `UInt32` values using a color bar that I've constructed such that the first pixel is pure red (0xff0000ff), and the last pixel is pure white (0xffffffff).  In none of the values do we see anything that translates to black.  When arrayed as a 64 by one map (it is essentially the color bar) it should look like this...

[image: 64x1 correct image]

but sometimes, just reinvokeing the drawrect method, with identical data and created buffer it looks completely wrong

[image: 64x1 incorrect image]

or sometimes *almost* right (one pixel the wrong color).  I would post more examples but I'm restricted to only two links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you've created a data provider with an unsafe pointer to `buffer`, filled that pixel buffer, created the image using that provider, but then allowed `buffer` fall out of scope and be released even though the data provider still had an unsafe reference to that memory address.

But once that memory was deallocated, it can be used for other things, rendering weird behavior ranging from a single pixel that is off, or wholesale alteration of that memory range as it's used for other things.

In Objective-C environment, I'd do a `malloc` of the memory when I created the provider, and then the last parameter to `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` would be a C function that I'd write to `free` that memory. (And that memory-freeing function may not be called until much later, not until the image was released.)

Another approach that I've used is to call `CGBitmapContextCreate` to create a context, and then use `CGBitmapContextGetData` to get the buffer it created for the image. I then can fill that buffer as I see fit. But because that buffer was created for me, the OS takes care of the memory management:

```
func createImageWithSize(size: NSSize) -> NSImage {
    let width = Int(size.width)
    let height = Int(size.height)

    let bitsPerComponent = 8
    let bytesPerRow = 4 * width
    let colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB()
    let bitmapInfo = CGImageAlphaInfo.PremultipliedLast.rawValue   // this depends upon how your `rgba` method was written; use whatever `bitmapInfo` that makes sense for your app

    let context = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, width, height, bitsPerComponent, bytesPerRow, colorSpace, bitmapInfo)!

    let pixelBuffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>(CGBitmapContextGetData(context))

    var currentPixel = pixelBuffer

    for row in 0 ..< height {
        for column in 0 ..< width {
            let red = ...
            let green = ...
            let blue = ...

            currentPixel.memory = rgba(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 255)
            currentPixel++
        }
    }

    let cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context)!

    return NSImage(CGImage: cgImage, size: size)
}
```

That yields:

[image]

One could make an argument that the first technique (create the data provider, doing a `malloc` of the memory and then providing `CGDataProviderCreateWithData` a function parameter to free it) might be better, but then you're stuck writing a C function to do that cleanup, something I'd rather not do in a Swift environment. But it's up to you.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  I wasn't seeing the "fall out of scope" -> release and deallocation connection.  I _thought_ it must have something to do with a memory deallocation/reuse but couldn't see how it was one of _mine_ given how use I've gotten to the Swift reference counter system.  I'm trying a variant of your second technique now, but am curious what the use of the `let x =` width/4 line was.

Comment: Sorry, that was a bit of unrelated code that I used for splitting up that gradient into four different zones to reproduce your image. But it is unrelated to the problem at hand, so I've removed that.